# magento site copy to subdirectory fatal error

Tags: php, magento

I copy my original magento site to sub directory and change some configurations(added new b,paths) but I'm getting a fatal error, i try 3 hours but no luck, here is my error log, can anyone pls help me solve this

original site working -

http://www.gingerlily.fr

getting error

http://www.gingerlily.fr/test/

http://www.gingerlily.fr/test/admin

```
  a:5:{i:0;s:92:"/var/www/vhosts/sd-14721.dedibox.fr/gingerlily/test/app/etc/modules/AdjustWare_Cartalert.xml";i:1;s:3081:"#0 /var/www/vhosts/sd-14721.dedibox.fr/gingerlily/test/app/code/local/Aitoc/Aitsys/Model/Aitfilesystem.php(290): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Aitfilesystem->_exception('/var/www/vhosts...')
    #1 /var/www/vhosts/sd-14721.dedibox.fr/gingerlily/test/app/code/local/Aitoc/Aitsys/Model/Module/License/Light/Performer/Reader.php(36) : eval()'d code(18) : eval()'d code(1300) : eval()'d code(1301): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Aitfilesystem->checkWriteable('/var/www/vhosts...', true)
    #2 /var/www/vhosts/sd-14721.dedibox.fr/gingerlily/test/app/code/local/Aitoc/Aitsys/Model/Module/License/Light/Performer/Reader.php(36) : eval()'d code(18) : eval()'d code(1300) : eval()'d code(1255): umgarcndqdwoztaoszakijpdewaqitesztefxqwp_Aitoc_Aitsys_Source_Abstract_Performer_Abstract->checkModuleConfigs()
    #3 /var/www/vhosts/sd-14721.dedibox.fr/gingerlily/test/app/code/local/Aitoc/Aitsys/Model/Module/License/Light/Performer/Reader.php(36) : eval()'d code(18) : eval()'d code(2046): umgarcndqdwoztaoszakijpdewaqitesztefxqwp_Aitoc_Aitsys_Source_Abstract_Performer_Abstract->checkStatus()
    #4 /var/www/vhosts/sd-14721.dedibox.fr/gingerlily/test/app/code/local/Aitoc/Aitsys/Model/Module/License.php(152): jyihtmxrtyyonagzwwzzfrkrexjifybrqdfdlcsx_Aitoc_Aitsys_Source_Light_Performer_Abstract->checkStatus()
    #5 /var/www/vhosts/sd-14721.dedibox.fr/gingerlily/test/app/code/local/Aitoc/Aitsys/Model/Module/License/Light.php(168): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Module_License->_checkStatus()
    #6 /var/www/vhosts/sd-14721.dedibox.fr/gingerlily/test/app/code/local/Aitoc/Aitsys/Model/Platform.php(416): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Module_License_Light->checkStatus()
    #7 /var/www/vhosts/sd-14721.dedibox.fr/gingerlily/test/app/code/local/Aitoc/Aitsys/Model/Observer.php(28): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Platform->reload()
    #8 /var/www/vhosts/sd-14721.dedibox.fr/gingerlily/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1272): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Observer->debugerInit(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
    #9 /var/www/vhosts/sd-14721.dedibox.fr/gingerlily/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1253): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Observer), 'debugerInit', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
    #10 /var/www/vhosts/sd-14721.dedibox.fr/gingerlily/test/app/Mage.php(416): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_fron...', Array)
    #11 /var/www/vhosts/sd-14721.dedibox.fr/gingerlily/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(147): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_fron...', Array)
    #12 /var/www/vhosts/sd-14721.dedibox.fr/gingerlily/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(712): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->init()
    #13 /var/www/vhosts/sd-14721.dedibox.fr/gingerlily/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1055): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initFrontController()
    #14 /var/www/vhosts/sd-14721.dedibox.fr/gingerlily/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(340): Mage_Core_Model_App->getFrontController()
    #15 /var/www/vhosts/sd-14721.dedibox.fr/gingerlily/test/app/Mage.php(627): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #16 /var/www/vhosts/sd-14721.dedibox.fr/gingerlily/test/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #17 {main}";s:3:"url";s:11:"/test/admin";s:11:"script_name";s:15:"/test/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aitoc_Aitsys says that a directory is not writable. Check http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions to see how to reset file permissions, and check to see if your Aitoc plugin needs another directory with writable permissions. http://www.aitoc.com/en/aitdownloadablefiles/download/aitfile/aitfile_id/503/ tells you which directories need to be writable.

Comment: hello, site is ok but url still shown as root site, have u any idea about this

Comment: You'll need to fix the base_url and secure/base_url to the correct directory. You most likely wouldn't be able to log into the admin to fix this, so you'll have to fix it within the database. You can find it in the core_config_data table.

Comment: You mean you searched for gingerlily.fr/test in your database? Try searching for base_url and see what it's set to. Also check your app/etc/local.xml to make sure it points to the correct database.